# how to call a back method from front asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, web

I'm trying to call a method written in the back from a div in the front

front:

```
 <div runat="server" id="headerLink" onclick="headerLinkOnClick" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <header>
            </header>
        </div>
```

back:

```
 protected void headerLinkOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Roles.DeleteCookie();
        Session.Clear();
        Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
    }
```

I must miss something but no idea what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a hidden button

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnPostback" style="display:none" onclick="headerLinkOnClick" />

<div onclick="document.getElementById('<%= btnPostback.ClientID %>').click()">Clickable DIV</div>
```